# column name in column -> copy specified column's value to single column

Tags: r, dplyr, vectorization

I have a dataset where I have column names in a column, and I'd like to copy the value of that column to a specific column.  While I can do this with purrrly::by_row() or apply(), this seems inefficient and I'm looking for a more vectorized solution if possible.

Here's a setup where I have column names in "my_col":

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library("dplyr"))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library("purrrlyr"))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library("tibble"))

my_mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
        rownames_to_column() %>%
        select(rowname, cyl, mpg, hp) %>%
        mutate(my_col = if_else(cyl == 6, "mpg", "hp"))
```

The dataset looks like:

```
               rowname cyl  mpg  hp my_col
1            Mazda RX4   6 21.0 110    mpg
2        Mazda RX4 Wag   6 21.0 110    mpg
3           Datsun 710   4 22.8  93     hp
4       Hornet 4 Drive   6 21.4 110    mpg
...
```

Here's a solution which simply calls a function for each row, putting value of the column specified in "my_col" to "my_val":

```
purrrlyr::by_row(my_mtcars, .collate="rows", .to="my_val",
                 function(x) { x[[ x[["my_col"]] ]] })

   rowname             cyl   mpg    hp my_col my_val
 1 Mazda RX4          6.00  21.0 110   mpg      21.0
 2 Mazda RX4 Wag      6.00  21.0 110   mpg      21.0
 3 Datsun 710         4.00  22.8  93.0 hp       93.0
 4 Hornet 4 Drive     6.00  21.4 110   mpg      21.4
 ...
```

I'm concerned that my by_row() approach above is very inefficient, since I'm basically iterating over each row.  Is there more efficient/vectorized solution?

I've noticed that dplyr::mutate() does not allow vectors when indexing into .data pronoun.  For instance, the following does NOT work:

```
mutate(my_mtcars, my_val = .data[[ .data[["my_col"]] ]])
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: Must subset with a string.
```

Comment: Dekan : Doesn;t only `my_mtcars$my_val <- ifelse(my_mtcars$my_col == "mpg", my_mtcars$mpg, my_mtcars$hp)` should give the desired result ?

Comment: That approach would undesirably make me if_else through all the possible values of my_mtcars$my_col, which could be very large (and not programmatically dynamic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the matrix accessor:

```
ind <- cbind(seq_len(nrow(my_mtcars)), 
             match(my_mtcars[["my_col"]], names(my_mtcars)))
my_mtcars$my_val <- my_mtcars[ind]
```